Primary vs. Secondary sources for Classical mythology
What are the primary sources for Classical mythology?
Unlike more modern religions (Christianity, Judaism, Islam, Buddism) Greco-Roman mythology doesn't have a specific foundation text. Indeed, those of us who have never studied Greek or Latin learn this mythology from "secondary" (or more likely third/fourth/fifth-party) accounts written in abundance by modern writers/popularizers. My guess is that those are compilations and systematization of information spread over many ancient writings - which raises the question of how much of the mythology is actually Greek/Roman, and how much emerged due to the choices made in processing the ancient sources. Indeed, one could expect the original sources to be just as contradictory, as, e.g., when we compare with modern Biblical canon versus numerous non-canonical texts and gospels.
On the other hand, the stories should be rather pervasive across multiple writings to qualify as mythology, rather than just as isolated works of fiction (I doubt anyone would describe Shakespear's plays as "mythology"... Star Wars or Lord of the Rings could be described as mythologies - but each of these is based on a single source.)
The Q. might be more about history than Classical languages, but I expect members of this community to have greater expertise on the subject than in History SE.

There's also a SE site for mythology.


My guess is that those are compilations and systematization of information spread over many ancient writings - which raises the question of how much of the mythology is actually Greek/Roman, and how much emerged due to the choices made in processing the ancient sources.

The compilation has been ongoing since the Graeco-Roman era. In fact, one could say that Hesiod, whose writings are among the oldest extant Greek literature, was a mythographer, though to him, it is probable that he considered the myths he compiled to be real.
Even disregarding some of the earlier "compilers" of myths like Hesiod, by the fifth century at least a distinction was made between mythical history and actual history, even if some works tried to bridge the two. Thus, someone like Hellanicus of Lesbos should qualify as a true mythographer. And then you get to Callimachus, Ps.-Apollodorus, Ovid, Hyginus, etc. So yes, many Greeks and Romans absolutely knew myths through compilations. The basic story was already written in antiquity.
What good mythographers do today is show the chronological development of the myths. When you read a pop Greek myth book, it's very likely to put the Trojan War in a complete context, beginning with the golden apple of Eris and ending with a Trojan Horse, yet e.g. the story of Thetis dipping Achilles in the river Styx, often mentioned as an indispensable part of the story, isn't recorded until Statius' Achilleid in the 1st century CE several hundred years after Homer's Iliad. Gantz' Early Greek Myth mentions that fact, but that's not clear in many other compilations.
Still, the facts presented do come actual ancient works, and the basic outline for Greek myth was created still in the classical age (with Hellanicus) and refined in the Roman era. It is not simply a modern creation.
As a side note:

On the other hand, the stories should be rather pervasive across multiple writings to qualify as mythology, rather than just as isolated works of fiction.

These labels are anachronistic, even for Shakespeare. I think the propagation of the novel led to the sharp division between fiction and non-fiction, but you can't really retroactively apply that backwards. For one, many believed in the myths. To them, it was history, even if stylized. And while some historians emphasized strict accuracy, others emphasized a good story with morals for the community to follow. Even then, the former included speeches that were clearly fabricated. It was essentially understood that the historian would write the dialogue for the actors in their histories.
It gets messier with myths. Plenty of good historians, like Thucydides, decried myths while still accepting their basic facts, like that there was a Trojan War. Who believed what particular fact is really uncertain, unless they state their beliefs outright.
